# disable notification in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python-telegram-bot

help me please.
How i can disable sound notifications in 'python-telegram-bot' library?
This code is not working:

```
update.effective_message.reply_text("any text",                                         
                                   disable_notification=True,reply_markup=test_keyboard)
```

or

```
context.bot.send_message(chat_id=context.chat_data.get('user').id,
                                 text="any text",
                                disable_notification=True,
                                reply_markup=greeting_keyboard)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply this in posting to channels. Users won't get notifications from the bot if and only if they mute it theirselves.